# Why didn't the Animorphs use their Leeran morphs after returning home?

Tags: animorphs, morphing

In [#18 The Decision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decision_(novel)), the Animorphs all acquire Leeran morphs. Since Leeran are telepathic and can read minds, it seems like quite a useful morph for espionage or interrogation of captured Yeerks.

Why did none of the Animorphs use their Leeran morphs after returning from Leera?

Comment: because a leeran would stick out in the world.  How else would you explain a frog monster?  So far when there was a Animorph/Yeerk battle, it's because of some sort of zoo accident, but this would be harder to explain.

Comment: @CBredlow Yeah, this is a fair reason. It would be kinda hard to hide a Leeran, lol.

Comment: @CBredlow The Chee could have probably helped with that, though? Project a hologram around the Leeran morph. And since espionage is not violent, the Chee might be able to help.

Comment: Not to mention the best use for a Leeran is interrogation.  Capture a known Controller, get them in a room with Ax, let him morph Leeran, get the info he needs, then you starve the Yeerk out.  OBVIOUSLY you don't use the frog men for fights, you use it as a means of flawless information gathering.

Comment: @Ketura Really good point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Because of the moral concerns involved with morphing sentient creatures

> **If the Animorphs morphed Leerans once, they should do it again, shouldn't they?**
>
> ***KAA:*** *No, because Leerans are sentient beings, and the Animorphs don't believe they have the right to appropriate the DNA of sentient beings without permission. On Leera they had permission. But now they have no way of asking the Leerans if they mind.*
> <sub>[Scholastic.com - "According to K.A." December 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/20000919005030/http://www.scholastic.com:80/animorphs/ka9812.htm)</sub>

Comment: Wish I could give you an extra +1 for the ancient Wayback Machine link.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of them acquired it --- only Jake, Marco, Cassie and Ax.
And I always thought it might have been unusable because they acquired the DNA using their "Snapback selves" (their original forms were still in mosquito morph, where their consciousness eventually snapped back to).

Hence, the original form did not possess the Leeran DNA.

Comment: Interesting answer.